# How do you fix kivy.graphics DLL issue?

Tags: python, kivy

Sigh...Here's another question about Python's never ending module issues. I have Python 3.4 and Windows 8. I can import Kivy fine, but if I try to import kivy.graphics, I ran into a DLL issue:

```
File "C:\Users\Young\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\__init__.py",  line 89, in <module>
 from kivy.graphics.instructions import Callback, Canvas, CanvasBase, \
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Does anybody have any clue?

Comment: Sounds like Kivy is maybe not compiled correctly. Are the shared object files present (e.g. kivy/graphics/instructions.dll, I guess)?

Comment: I think graphics.instruction is dependent on Callback, Canvas, and Canvasbase modules. But they don't appear to be in the Kivy directory. But, I might have overlooked those given that there's hundreds of files in dozens of folders.

Comment: Try my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36146464/3163618

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, and fixed it by re-installing kivy as an administrator.

Right-click on cmd.exe and select "Run as administrator." Then follow the install instructions [here](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#installation-windows).

Comment: I had same isseus and other depns. issues, when install kivy or any other pip for window, always run as administrator, this really fix issues.