# How to Fix Kivy Issue Sdl2 -import Error? (Already tried pip'ing it)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

This is my code which I copied stright from the `kivy website` to test the library.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
    return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

I get this error

```
C:\Users\Helquin\PycharmProjects\Reddit\ok\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Helquin/PycharmProjects/Reddit/Guiexample.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Helquin\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-09-19_40.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.1.17
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.1.12
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.1.22
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Helquin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Helquin\PycharmProjects\Reddit\ok\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\Helquin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Helquin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried uninstalling and re-installing as mentioned in [sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found and [CRITICAL] [App] Unable to get a Window, abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482753/sdl2-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-and)[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943224/how-can-i-bypass-kivy-module-error-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified)

I also tried to follow a video made this year in case I made some mistake but that didn't help.

(I am using Pycharms, on a windows 10 (home) 64 bit, 16 Gb ram

Comment: `SDL2` is a library created with C/C++ which you can download from https://www.libsdl.org/

Comment: Did you install SDL2 *in the environment pycharm is using*?

Comment: So in case, anyone else has this issue, I just made it in pycharm then ran it straight from CMD. Not sure why this works, but even the developers couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

So in case, anyone else has this issue, I just made it in pycharm then ran it straight from CMD. Not sure why this works, but even the developers couldn't figure it out